# ionic 4 different language fonts

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

I want to add font-family to another language which I'm using in my ionic 4 app. I tried

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'SINHA Sithumina 2012';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: url('./assets/font/SINHA Sithumina 2012.ttf');
}
```

and use it in html css class. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Downvoted... this literally took me 2 seconds to google - https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-css-lang.en

Comment: @marblewraith I have already try it. but it doesn't apply to my ionic project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I have solved the issue by referring https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-css-lang.en which mention by @marblewraith.

So basically I have to mention my words in utf and it will convert my fonts.

Answer (score 1):

@kavindhi

First thing first you should do to convert you `.ttf` font family into `.otf`.
https://convertio.co/ttf-otf/

Then add your font's into assets folder.

Then you should add into into global.scss or add custom file like `fonts.scss`

Then add this into your font file

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "SolitaireMVBPro-Regular";
  src: url("assets/fonts/SolitaireMVBPro-Regular.otf");
}
```

So it'll be available for you into your ionic 4 pages

```
  font-family: SolitaireMVBPro-Regular;
```

Comment: already tried.. I have solve the issue by referring https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-css-lang.en